# Is this because of floating point errors?

Tags: r, debugging, floating-point, statistics, probability

I'm not understanding how to fix this problem. `G` is a set of values for which I know that the range is `[0, 1e+12]`.

```
> G = c(500,10000, 5001, 103, 10, 10000)
> H = density(G)
> sum(diff(H$x)*H$y) # Area under the curve should be 1

[1] 0.999989
```

However, to be able to compare two datasets, I want to provide `from` and `to` to the `density` function so that it makes sense to compare these distributions. Therefore, I did this:

```
> H = density(G, from=0, to=1e+12)
> sum(diff(H$x)*H$y)

[1] 2576.354

Warning message:
In diff(H$x) * H$y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The reason became evident when I printed the estimated densities:

```
[1] 1.315415e-04 1.102126e-07 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 9.471181e-26
  [8] 1.565915e-22 2.563577e-26 4.272754e-23 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 8.951887e-26 1.516549e-22
 [15] 3.870985e-25 6.612221e-22 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.275922e-25 2.216194e-22 0.000000e+00
 [22] 0.000000e+00 5.567175e-26 9.835567e-23 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.866999e-25 3.355962e-22
 [29] 1.544394e-25 2.800493e-22 6.026824e-26 1.102559e-22 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
....
....
[484] 2.430850e-22 1.346442e-25 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.135491e-22 6.399622e-26 0.000000e+00
[491] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
[498] 8.914726e-23 5.240562e-26 2.189813e-22 1.297914e-25 4.773404e-22 2.852380e-25 3.289275e-22
[505] 1.981486e-25 1.382136e-23 8.393153e-27 8.090789e-24 4.952458e-27 3.042214e-24 1.876931e-27
[512] 1.809917e-22
```

While R is correctly estimating the density to be 0 at extreme points, some are non-zero. Is this a floating point error I'm facing or am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure, but wouldn't it seem that a good clue would be the descriptions of the arguments `from, to` and `cut` in `?density`. Looks like by setting the range so far beyond the limits of your data you're circumventing something that `density` typically does by default to ensure (essentially) zero density at the extremes.

Comment: This makes sense and that is what I originally thought. However, it just seemed intuitively wrong to compare two distributions with very different range (please correct me if I am wrong). The original suggestion came from @mbq in another question that I posted: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47885/k-l-divergence-is-0-for-clearly-different-distributions-why

Comment: The first bin is too wide to approximate your data at all.

Comment: As a side point, I recently noticed zapsmall in base for pushing small numbers that can be reasonably assumed to be zero back to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'mon. You failed to reproduce the warning message. I suspect that is the key to the discrepancy. the `diff(x)` function gives you a vector that is one element shorter than the y.

R operations include argument recycling, so the first density diff element will get multiplied by the largest y element.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question to contain the warning. I apologize in advance for not understanding your answer but can you elaborate on how this is causing the area under the curve to spike up?

Comment: +1 Great! Thank you for the explanation. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: To be fair, I'm accepting this as an answer because its the closest reason to why this is happening. Please let me know if there is a way to fix this.

Comment: Why not: `sum(diff(H$x)*H$y[-length(H$y)])` or `sum(diff(H$x)*H$y[-1])`. I'm not sure which one would be best. It appears your data is highly skewed.